# How to do 301 redirects on pages from non https www. html pages to a WordPress site with https and no www AND totally different keywords in URLs?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-routing, http-status-code-301

I’m moving a 180 page html non https site over to WordPress and to https AND changing the keywords of the URLs in an .htaccess file

AND some of the files are http: //www.site.com/keyword-abc.html

and some don’t have the www, I.e., they’re http: //site.com/keyword-abc.html

So I need to manually find some way to list both the html files
http: //www.site.com/keyword-abc.html

And the

http: //site.com/keyword-abc.html

And redirect it not only to https but also change the URL after the domain name like

https: //site.com/new-keyword-that-ranks/

I don’t want to use a WordPress plugin to do it but .htaccess file in Apache.

How to I write the code for moving both the www and the non www insecure urls to https and totally different keywords in the htaccess file?

I know I will have to write a line of code or two for each URL I want to change.

Does it matter if I do the http: //www.site.com/keyword-abc.html first before the http: //site.com/keyword-abc.html  in the redirect?

If I put a space between each URL change to be able to see and trouble shoot it easier, will that affect the speed of the redirects or cause any problems?

I’ve gone over lots of tutorials for .htaccess and have never seen any of them that does both a www non secure to https redirect, AND an http:// no www to https redirect  AND different keywords in the new URL.

I think the hard part is the different keywords after the domain name but I've already built the site with those URLs in it.

This is for a .htaccess file for an Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Would this code work?

## 301 Redirect 1

RewriteRule ^addintheworkplacearticles.html$ https://example.com/manage-adhd-at-work/ [R=301,L]

## 301 Redirect 2

`enter code here`RewriteRule ^adhdmedicationart.html$ https://example.com/adhd-medication-articles/ [R=301,L] `enter code here`

## 301 Redirect 3

`enter code here`RewriteRule ^adhdmedicationco.html$ https://example.com/adhd-medication-company-websites/ [R=301,L] `enter code here`

## continue this on all the other individual page to page redirects, then paste this code after it

## Redirect non-HTTP or non-www to HTTPS without www

`enter code here`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(example.com)$? 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] `enter code here`

than after that code, put the WordPress htaccess code